# Using variable as column name in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am creating a series of data.tables via a loop where each tables name and columns are dependent on the loop.

I found I can use `assign` to create the table and then use `eval(as.name(tbl))` to then call it which seems to work ok.  The column name doesn't seem to be behaving quite like I want though?

To generate the column name I use `capture.output(str(tbl, give.head = F))` which works but then when I want to reference the column it is surrounded by double quotes e.g. `"name_win_pcnt"`

I can't seem to reference the column either so if I use name_win_pcnt$"name_win_pcnt" I get a NULL in the console.

Here is an example.

```
require(data.table)
# initial data table
dt <- data.table(x = rnorm(10),
             y = rnorm(10),
             grp = c(rep("a",3), rep("b",7))))

#variables
metric <- c("win", "place")
cols <- "name"

tbl <- paste0(cols, "_", metric[1],"_pcnt")

# create new table and create new column
assign(tbl, dt, envir = .GlobalEnv)
eval(as.name(tbl))[, capture.output(str(tbl, give.head = F)) := 0L, by = .(grp)]
```

If I now try and update the new column using

`eval(as.name(tbl))[, eval(tbl) := 1L, by = .(grp)]` this creates me a new column but leaves the old one?

I tried adding the column using `eval(as.name(tbl))[, eval(tbl) := 0L]` but then when I try and update it I get an error:

```
Error in is.nan(name_win_pcnt) : 
  default method not implemented for type 'list'
```

Comment: Do not use `assign`. Put all these data.tables in a list.

Comment: I create the tables 1 at a time using my outer loop. Why should I avoid assign?

Comment: Because of the kind of problems you are encountering ... `assign` is for experts who know when it is needed (almost never). Using a list (or environment) is the "R way".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the usage of the `set` command would be more in the spirit of the `data.table` package and can do the job.

```
 set(x=eval(as.name(tbl)), j=tbl, value=2L)
```

This way, no quotation marks are in the column name.

Althought you didn't ask, I feel that using lists to hold all data.tables together would make better use of R's data structures.

Comment: apologies I should have mentioned I use I need to perform operations on groups so I don't think `set` will work in this case. 
I will update my question.

Comment: maybe you can do the subset operation before and use `set` in a second step on an intermediate result? In a third step you could update the data in the original data.table again with `set`.

Comment: Thanks doing the intermediate step seems to have worked. So I create the column using my original method, then use set to update it and it seems to cure the problem.
It seems using variables is quite hard work in R?

Comment: It is unusual and I don't do it very often, but it is feasible, the language can deal with it. If your case works with `set`, please mark my answer as accepted. Thanks!